# How to increment mixed Alphanumeric in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, increment, alphanumeric

I have requirements in a project to generate sequential rows and columns which are alphanumeric values.

The end user will pass the start value of row and column he would like to start from, and how many rows and columns he wants to generate.

For letters the max value is Z

For numbers the max values is 9

If the end user passed these parameters:

StartRow = 0A

StartColumn = A9Z

rowsCount = 2

columnsCount = 5

I would like to get this result:

[image: Output Result]

Comment: I don't know why this question has been down voted?

Comment: @PaulF You're right. Also I have posted a simple answer below.
Thanks for reply

Comment: Looking at your code - I now realise I am wrong - you are incrementing Alphabetic & Numeric independently - so "0Z" + 1 would be "1A" whereas base36 it would be "10".

Comment: @PaulF Yea I have mentioned in my question if the passed char is letter the max is Z and it 's number the max is 9

Comment: Did you just ask and answer your own question within the same minute?

Comment: @TheJoker Yea I have found out some people trying the achieve that.So I have posted question and my answer to share that with them.

Comment: So you already knew the answer?

Comment: @TheJoker Yea I know and I know that this does not break the rules of Stack Overflow

Comment: Haha, you really want that badge, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with very simple solution to implement that and I would like to share this Console application  :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var row = "0A";
        var column = "A9Z";
        var rowsCount = 2;
        var columnsCount = 5;
        var rowCharArray =row.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray();
        var columnCharArray = column.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
            {
                columnCharArray = incrementChar(columnCharArray);
                var currentColumn = string.Join("", columnCharArray.Reverse().ToArray());
                var currentRow= string.Join("", rowCharArray.Reverse().ToArray());

                Console.WriteLine(currentRow  + "-" + currentColumn);
            }
            columnCharArray = column.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray();
            rowCharArray= incrementChar(rowCharArray);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static char[] incrementChar(char[] charArray,int currentIndex=0)
    {
        char temp = charArray[currentIndex];

        if (charArray.Length -1 == currentIndex && (temp == '9' || temp == 'Z'))
            throw new Exception();

        temp++;
        if(Regex.IsMatch(temp.ToString(),"[A-Z]"))
        {
            charArray[currentIndex] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(temp.ToString(), "[0-9]"))
            {
                charArray[currentIndex] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                currentIndex++;
                incrementChar(charArray, currentIndex);
            }
        }
        if (currentIndex != 0)
            charArray = resetChar(charArray, currentIndex);

        return charArray;
    }

    static char[] resetChar(char[] charArray,int currentIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
        {
            if (charArray[i] == 'Z')
                charArray[i] = 'A';
            else if (charArray[i] == '9')
                charArray[i] = '0';
        }
        return charArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider replacing your regular expressions with calls to `Char.IsDigit` and `Char.IsLetter`.

Comment: @JimMischel yea you're right it would make sense more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider your approach. Rather than maintaining an alphanumeric value and trying to increment it, maintain the value as a class containing `Row` and `Column` values, and then use `ToString` to convert it to the alphanumeric representation. Like this:

```
class RowCol
{
    private int _row;
    private int _col;

    public int Row
    {
        get { return _row; }
        set
        {
            // Row is of the form <digit><letter
            // giving you 260 possible values.
            if (value < 0 || value > 259)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            _row = value;
        }
    }

    public int Col
    {
        get { return _col; }
        set
        {
            // Col is <letter><digit><letter>,
            // giving you 6,760 possible values
            if (value < 0 || value > 6759)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            _col = value;
        }
    }

    public string RowString
    {
        get
        {
            // convert Row value to string
            int r, c;
            r = Math.DivMod(_row, 26, out c);
            r += '0';
            c += 'A';
            return string.Concat((char)r, (char)c);
        }
        set
        {
            // convert string to number.
            // String is of the form <letter><digit>
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length != 2
                || !Char.IsDigit(value[0] || !Char.IsUpper(value[1]))
                throw new ArgumentException();
            _row = 26*(value[0]-'0') + (value[1]-'A');
        }
    }

    public string ColString
    {
        get
        {
            int left, middle, right remainder;
            left = Math.DivRem(_col, 260, out remainder);
            middle = Math.DivRem(remainder, 26, out right);
            left += 'A';
            middle += '0';
            right += 'A';
            return string.Concat((char)left, (char)middle, (char)right);
        }

        set
        {
            // Do standard checking here to make sure it's in the right form.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length != 3
                || !Char.IsUpper(value[0] || !Char.IsDigit(value[1]) || !Char.IsUpper(value[2]))
                throw new ArgumentException();

            _col = 260*(value[0] - 'A');
            _col += 26*(value[1] - '0');
            _col += value[2] - 'A';
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return RowString + '-' + ColString;
    }

    public RowCol(int row, int col)
    {
        Row = _row;
        Col = _col;
    }

    public RowCol(string row, string col)
    {
        RowString = row;
        RowString = col;
    }
}
```

(Code not yet tested, but that's the general idea.)

That's a bit more code than you have, it hides the complexity in the `RowCol` class rather than forcing you to deal with it in your main program logic. The point here is that you just want to increment the row or column; you don't want to have to think about *how* that's done. It makes your main program logic easier to understand. For example:

```
string startRow = "0A";
string startCol = "B0A";
RowCol rc = new RowCol("0A", "B0A");
for (int r = 0; r < rowsCount; r++)
{
    rc.ColString = "B0A";
    for (int c = 0; c < columnsCount; c++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rc);
        rc.Row = rc.Row + 1;
    }
    rc.Col = rc.Col + 1;
}
```

By casting this as a simple conversion problem and encapsulating it in a class, I've made the code more robust and flexible, and easier to test, understand, and use.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree with you but the code snippet I have provided it's for demonstrations purposes and for simplicity even I have hard coded the input parameters inside the main method.